# C++ to D interoperability

Tags: c++, d

Since days im trying to call some D code from C++ (with an class/interface defined for C++ and D).

the D code

```
module BufferCppBinding;

extern (C++) void *createBufferCppBinding() {
    BufferCppBinding ptr = new BufferCppBinding();
    return cast(void*)ptr;
}

extern (C++) interface BufferCppBindingInterface {
    void construct();
    // ...
}

class BufferCppBinding : BufferCppBindingInterface {
    public Buffer thisPtr;

    public extern (C++) void construct() {
        // doesn't do anything
    }
}
```

the C++ code for declaring the type to C++ land:

```
class BufferCppBinding {
public:

    virtual void construct();
};
```

for the initialisation of the D runtime i wrote a small function in D which does in D land:

```
extern (C++) void initDRuntime() nothrow{
    try
    {
        Runtime.initialize();
        //result = myWinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, iCmdShow);
        //Runtime.terminate(&exceptionHandler);
    }
    catch (Throwable o)
    {
        //MessageBox(null, o.toString().toUTF16z, "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        //result = 0;
    }
}
```

usage (C++):

```
BufferCppBinding *vertexBuffer = reinterpret_cast<BufferCppBinding*>(createBufferCppBinding());

// here happens the crash
vertexBuffer->construct();
```

I am compiling the code with g++ 5.2 and ldc2 and linking it with ldc2.

I just get a SIGSEGV.

Comment: Should your declaration in c++ be that of the D interface (BufferCppBindingInterface)?
http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html

Answer (score 2):

Returning pointers to C++ that point to the GC heap is a bad idea - use `malloc`/`emplace` (or `std.experimental.allocator.make) instead and call`free`on the C++ side. That won't run destructors though, so maybe you want to expose a D function that calls`destroy` as well.

BTW, no need to return `void*` and cast back - just return `BufferCppBindingInterface` from `createBufferCppBinding`.